# .NET Core 2.1 HttpClient doesn't return expected values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using an interface to call an api from this url http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/GetList

This is the controller its referencing:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetList")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> GetList()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

However, instead of the strings returning, I'm getting this:

[image]

This is how I'm declaring my httpclient/interface:

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
public AuthenticationClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDataAsync()
{
    List<string> result = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/GetList");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<string>>();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have already declared it in my Startup.cs as services.AddHttpClient();

This is how I call the interface

```
private readonly IAuthenticationClient authenticationClient;
public HomeController(IAuthenticationClient authenticationClient)
{
    this.authenticationClient = authenticationClient;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = authenticationClient.GetData();
    return View();
}
```

Have I missed something or is there a tutorial on how to use HttpClients? Also, how do I post data through this?

Comment: " is there a tutorial on how to use HttpClients"  ==> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: First ensure that you have a base [Route(“account”)] on top of your controller so that the action Route(“GetList”) will not be at the root /api/Getlist or better use [HttpGet(“GetList”)] and delete the route decoration on the action method

Answer (score 4):

your interface defines an async call.  in other words "GetData" returns `Task<string>` not that actual value.

In order to get the actual values try this (coding free hand so not debugged)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var result = await authenticationClient.GetData();
    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question based on what I found in the initial link you gave me. I have also changed my index to look like yours but I get null as a result now.

Answer (score 0):

I make it when I change controller code to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var result = await _authenticationClient.GetDataAsync();
        return View();
    }
```

Modify GetDataAsync()

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/api/Accounts/GetList");
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 2.1 includes a new `IHttpClientFactory` service that makes it easier to configure and consume instances of `HttpClient` in apps. `HttpClient` already has the concept of delegating handlers that could be linked together for outgoing HTTP requests. The factory:

- Makes registering of instances of HttpClient per named client more
  intuitive.
- Implements a Polly handler that allows Polly policies to be used for
  Retry, CircuitBreakers, etc.

For more information, see [Initiate HTTP Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).