# .NET Core 2.1 Consuming REST API doesn't return results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is how I am currently trying to consume a REST API

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public HomeController(IAuthenticationClient authenticationClient)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    this.authenticationClient = authenticationClient;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = GetList();
    return View();
}

public async Task<List<string>> GetList()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("GetList");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<string>>();
    }
    return new List<string>();
}
```

This is the API that is being called:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetList")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> GetList()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

The issue is that if I test it on Postman, I get the correct result which is value1 and value2, however, when I call it from my api client, I get this weird result instead of the correct ones.

[image]

I have already tried so many different guides but non of them seem to work. Is there a library to handle REST apis for .net core 2.1? Or am I better off just using the httpclient?

Comment: If it is working from postman, get the code from postman by clicking code link near to save button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the answer to your original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751720/2309376) you are missing the keyword `await` when you call the `GetList` method. Let's review your code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = GetList();
    return View();
}

public async Task<List<string>> GetList()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("GetList");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<string>>();
    }
    return new List<string>();
}
```

Your method `GetList` returns `Task<List<string>>`. When you return a `Task` you need to `await` the task to finish before you can access the results. Otherwise you will just get a `Task` object. If you look at your debug window you can see that the properties listed there match the ones belonging to a `Task`.

So, how do you wait for a task to finish so you can get the results? Use the `await` keyword.
The best way to fix this is to make your `Index` method async as well

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var result = await GetList();
    return View(result);
}
```

We have changed the method signature to include the `async` keyword and also wrap the result in a `Task`.
The changes here mean you can now `await` for the task returned by the `GetList` method to finish and the `result` variable will hold your `List<string>` data which you can then pass to the view.

More can be found on async and await [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)